# Checking whether a list of numbers contains ANY five number sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that only includes positive integers:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15, 16]
```

The list is sorted.

What would be the most "pythonic" way to check whether the list contains *any* sequence of `x` consequtive number? It shouldn't matter whether the sequence starts at the beginning of the list, or ends at the end of the list - as long as it's in the list, it should return true. For instance, if I wanted to check if the following list contains a 4-number sequence:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

It should return true due to `[3, 4, 5, 6]`

I have seen multiple StackOverflow questions about "finding number sequences in lists", however none of them dealt with looking for a sequence in only a *portion* of the list. (What I found was useful only if the goal was to check whether the entire list is sequential.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one liner:

```
def has_sequence(L, seq_len):
    return any(list(L[i:i+seq_len]) == list(range(L[i],L[i]+seq_len))
               for i in range(len(L)-seq_len+1))
```

Comment: Hi James, would it be possible for you to explain what is going on in this code?

Comment: After mulling over the code, I understand it fully now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def findRun(L, n):
    runlen = 0
    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        if L[i] == L[i-1]+1:
            runlen += 1
        else:
            runlen = 0
        if runlen == n-1:
            print("Found a run starting at", i-n+1)
```

Output:

```
In [451]: L = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]

In [452]: findRun(L, 4)
Found a run starting at 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:
after grouping them with the difference, you just check if any of the groups contains your preferred number of consecutive sequence(in this case 4).

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
my_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
check = False
 for key, group in groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda (i, val): i - val):
    g = map(itemgetter(1), group)
    if len(g) == 4:
        check = True
print(check)
```

> True

I hope this is what you looking for.